# How to target all children, not just first level?

Tags: jquery, list, children

This will target all first level children:

```
$(this).children()
```

How can I target all children not just first level, but childrens children and so on?

Comment: Why did somebody give me a -1?

Comment: I did not vote on your post. The downvote is possibly because this is a rather simple question which could have been solved by looking at the docs of `children()`.

Answer (score 4):

Then you mean *descendants*.

You can use

```
$(this).find('*')
```

---

Taken from the [documentation of `.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) (emphasis added):

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while **`.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.**

Comment: No idea... this is definitely an accurate answer and it was also first. Never mind the **AWESOME** edits that were made ;)

Comment: The original answer was incorrect, FYI. (did not downvote, but just trying to shed some light for you).

Answer (score 4):

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Unlike most of the tree traversal methods, the selector expression is required in a call to .find(). If we need to retrieve all of the descendant elements, we can pass in the universal selector '*' to accomplish this.

You need to add a selector within .find() (unlike .children()), so just add the asterisk.

Hence, `$(this).find('*');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** method in jQuery to get all children's at any level . Use `*` to target all item

```
$(this).find('*')
```